# Why char size increases as instance variable

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn’t sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)
>   [How is the size of a C++ class determined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510711/how-is-the-size-of-a-c-class-determined)

When I check the size of the class with single char variable, it's size is 1 Byte. But if we add an integer, suddenly it goes to 8. Can you please explain Why?

```
class Char
{
  char b;
};
class Int
{
  int a;
};
class A
{
  int a;
  char b;
};

int main()
{
  Char Cobj;
  cout<<"Char size: "<<sizeof(Cobj)<<endl;
  Int Iobj;
  cout<<"Int size: "<<sizeof(Iobj)<<endl;
  A aobj;
  cout<<"A size: "<<sizeof(aobj)<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The output is:
Char size: 1
Int size: 4
A size: 8

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510711/how-is-the-size-of-a-c-class-determined

Comment: Hmm these guys covered in deeper level. Thanx for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of padding - 3 dummy bytes will be added after `A::b`.

This is done to properly align `A` in, say, an array - the first member of `A` is an `int`, which has to have a specific alignment (4 or 8 bytes probably). So if you have

```
A arrayOfA[10];
```

the objects themselves have to be aligned to `4` or `8` bytes.