# How to load a C struct from a file in Octave or Matlab

Tags: c, matlab, signal-processing, octave, data-science

I have an array of C struct's like

```
typedef struct{
    uint32_t timestamp;
    uint16_t channels[4];
    float    value;
} sample_t;
```

Which is write to a file with something like

```
fwrite(&sample,sizeof(sample_t),1,fpLog)
```

What's a good way to load this into a array of **struct** in Octave/Matlab?

**Edit:** The goal is optimization for speed. The files are 1GB+ big and take a very long time to load in matlab. The files load 100x faster in numpy.

Comment: you can do it with a mex function

Comment: I think you should upload an example of your generated file (perhaps 10 samples) and provide a link

Comment: If speed is the goal write an OCT file. It would take less than 30 lines of C++ sourcecode. And you have the benefit that you can define the struct in a header and include it from your exporting prog and from the reading OCT file so you can easily extent your struct.

Comment: This question is unclear: does the data loading need to work in **both** MATLAB and Octave, does it need to work in one of them, or are you just using Octave and *think* that it’s the same as MATLAB?

Answer (score 1):

There is aligned rules for each C/C++ struct/class. See for example Eric Postpischil's answer in [How is the size of a C++ class determined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510711/how-is-the-size-of-a-c-class-determined). Very imported citate:

> For elementary types (int, double, et cetera), the alignment requirements are implementation dependent and are largely determined by the hardware.

So aligned rules for C/C++ compiler and Matlab/Octave can be different. You can solve yore problem:

1. Write data to file by components:

   ```
   fwrite(&sample.timestamp,sizeof(sample.timestamp),1,fpLog)
   fwrite(sample.channels,sizeof(sample.channels[0]),sizeof(sample.channels)/sizof(sample.channels[0]),fpLog)
   fwrite(&sample.value,sizeof(sample.value),1,fpLog)
   ```
2. Read file in Matlab/Octave by componets too:

   ```
   ts = fread(fplog,"uint32");
   sample.timestamp = ts;
   ch = fread(fplog,"uint16",4);
   sample.channels = ch;
   vl = fread(fplog,"float32");
   sample.value = vl;
   sample
   ```

Do not forget to open files in binary mode!!!

Comment: Hi, Good point on alignment in the struct. You could also mention endianes. with this one. Your suggestion works but it's slow.

Answer (score 0):

A trick : one can generate the .m I/O statements by parsing the C-struct definition with the [GDB Python API](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python-API.html).
When the binary file to read is produced by an ELF/object/executable and you have a Debug (gcc -g) version of it.